# eclipse 2023-09 project facet, dynamic web module 5.0, wildfly 23.0 runtime is dimmed

Tags: eclipse, wildfly

In eclipse 2023-09, I right click the project properties, Project Facet, and in dynamic web module, in the right hand side, choose runtimes tab, show all runtimes, wildfly 23.0 runtime is dimmed, if I uncheck dynamic web module checkbox, wildfly 23.0 runtimes checkbox is enabled, but an error "Dynamic Web Module 5.0 cannot be uninstalled" is shown and the apply button is dimmed. why?

2. And the project has many error like "javax.servlet.jsp" cannot be resolved to a type, is this related to above problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That version of Wildfly only supports up to version 4.